# What kind of halo is this?

Tags: the-sun, optics

My friend sent me a video of a kind of a halo phenomenon and asked me what kind of halo it is.

There is a 22 degree circular halo around the sun.

But there is also a ring which seems to go horizontally around the entire sky. The ring is the same height as the sun. It seems to start and end where the 22 halo is at the same height as the sun (3 and 9 o'clock on the halo) and goes horizontally around the sky.

Comment: Good question, but this is one for Earth Science. Halos are generated low in the atmosphere.

Comment: @JamesK Atmospheric effects that have an impact on astronomical observations should be on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it looks something like this? https://cloud.planetmaker.de/index.php/s/RkmkBNfb8YyDHSE

That sounds like the circum-horizontal ring (yes a name as simple as that). It (probably) is caused by hexagonal ice crystals floating horizontally. Where it touches the 22° halo you might see sun dogs which can be slightly colourful brighter patches.

See also https://www.meteoros.de/themen/halos/haloarten/ (German) and http://www.atoptics.co.uk/halosim.htm

Comment: see also [Why are these patterns of scattered sunlight aligned to the local horizontal and vertical directions?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/14451/6031)